# What is the difference between values and principles?

Tags: meaning

I am attempting to understand the use of values and principles in organizational communication.

According to [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/) [values](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/values) are defined as

- the amount of money that something is worth
- the price or cost of something something that can be bought for a low or fair price
- usefulness or importance

And [principles](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/principles) are defined as

- a moral rule or belief that helps you know what is right and wrong
  and that influences your actions
- a basic truth or theory : an idea that forms the basis of something
- a law or fact of nature that explains how something works or why
  something happens

Blogs such [BrokenMindSet](http://brokenmindset.org/principles-vs-values/) and [EnergizedWork](http://www.energizedwork.com/weblog/2006/12/values-practices-principles) describe them differently as are the terms when searching online.

For example, these are some of the [principles](http://www.cioupdate.com/insights/article.php/3936706/The-4-Principles-of-a-Successful-Data-Strategy.htm) that can be found by searching online

- Operation efficiency
- Retain and grow revenue
- Establish barriers to competition

These are examples of [values](http://www.driveyoursuccess.com/2010/06/how-can-strategic-planning-help-your-business-grow.html)

- Customer-centric
- Accountability
- Integrity

How do i use these terms in organizational conversations?

- How does one differentiate between principles and values?
- How do you define principles and what would be examples of these?
- How do you define values and what would be examples of these?

Comment: It would be beneficial to provide context that warrants a downvote so that i can update or amend the question.

Comment: **Principles are laws that govern human nature and relationships.** I would be very skeptical of anyone or any website that promoted this definition, since it is simplistic indeed. Gravity determines our physical characteristics, but nothing "governs" human nature, and you only have to look at human history for the last three millennia (or even just the last three months) to see how complex, varied, and often evil it is.

Comment: @Cargill - How would you define principles then as well as values?

Comment: Frankly, the variation in definitions of the two words are so great that it's meaningless to try to draw a fine distinction between them.  One man's values are another man's prejudices, and a third man's habits.

Comment: @Hot Licks - Thanks. I'm not attempting to draw a fine distinction rather where each plays a role in organizational communication. I appreciate people using them in varying contexts however i imagine principles driving values which in turn drive habit and practices as much as prejudices.

Comment: The point is that if you are using the terms in something like a business "statement of principles" you need to first define what you mean by "principles", and if you are also writing a "statement of values" you need to even more precisely define the distinction between the two.  There are not "standard" definitions that will distinguish one from the other (and draw a line between them) in such a context.

Comment: @Hot Licks - Thanks Hot Licks. That's what i am trying to do however i am unsure the definition of principles and values in the context of business communication and hence am citing examples i have found.

Comment: @Motivated- from that standpoint I  actually think values drive principles.

Comment: Well, you've got to settle on definitions that suit your situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Values are things that give us the sense of right and wrong whereas principles are rules of any subject or area. We live our lives following values. For example:

> 'Being honest' and 'speaking the truth' are values.
>
> 'Gravity'is a principle of physics.

Comment: Thanks. How do you apply these in the context of organizational conversations as in the examples provided?

Comment: @Motivated - see my edited answer

Comment: Thanks however that doesn't answer my question regarding organizational conversations e.g. What is operational efficiency? Is it a value or principle?

Comment: @Motivated 'Operational efficiency' is a benchmark, not a value or principle.

Comment: If operational efficiency is a benchmark, what are examples of organizational principles and values?

Comment: @Motivated - Kirti is correct. Example of organisational principles and values: "Representing correct facts in advertisements is what we adhere to as one of our organisational values". I think, now you are clear.

Comment: @Dinesh Kumar Garg - So would you define value as something intrinsically desirable while principles are rules of conduct? For example, would you define simplicity as a value i.e. we seek simplicity in our approach and stability as a principle i.e. we want stable solutions. Are you able to provide an answer that speaks to various organizational values and principles?

Comment: @Motivated - "Simplicity" may be a principle also. For example, I may take a principle that I would maintain austerity and would not spend on expensive clothes and would wear plain clothes only. Again, I may make take a principle that I would never tell a lie. This is a principle to me, though it is intrinsically desirable. To my mind, "principle" is a wider term, overlapping what the word "value" conveys. Thus, one may believe in a principle called "honesty" or a value called "honesty". But, a principle of physics cannot be called a value of physics.